# Dymola Issue: "Dymosim.exe has stopped working"

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am running large-scale thermal-fluid system simulation with Dymola 2012.

At the end of simulation I received the following warning message: "Dymosim.exe has stopped working". I could workaround this by clicking the "Close program" (another option is to click "Debug") and simulation could successfully finish afterwards. However, this gives some trouble when running a parametric study and I have to manually click the "Close program" for each run.

Has anybody experienced such issues with Dymola? I would appreciate very much if you could share some suggestions for me. The above problem happens both for 32bit and 64bit Dymola 2012 and I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition as the compiler.

Thanks a lot,

Pengfei

Comment: Is updating to Dymola 2013 or 2013FD01 or 2014 an option? Might be worth a try. And probably end of November the next Dymola version will be released.

Answer (score 2):

This is really an issue for Dymola support.  There really isn't a question here about programming.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is likely from the Windows Error Reporting service and not from Dymola.